# Angular2: update view after discarding change in text input

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have an array of text areas which can be updated individually and the changes can be saved or discarded. Each textarea is represented by an object to keep track of the changes and to enable/disable some buttons. Everything is working fine, but after the discard, the object is not changed, but the view is not updated. It only gets updated, when I change something inside the object, so I tried to make a 'real' copy of the object and assign those values to the actual object, but this also does not work.
My code so far:

HTML:

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let itemId of itemIds">
  <div>
        <div>
            <textarea #message (keydown)="enableButton(itemId)" rows="5" cols="50"[(value)]="getMessageDetails(itemId).message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button [disabled]="!getMessageDetails(itemId).changedText" (click)="saveMessageChanges(itemId, message.value)">Save Changes</button>
        <button [disabled]="!getMessageDetails(itemId).changedText" (click)="discardChanges(itemId)">Discard Changes</button>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Component:

```
    itemIds = [2,4];

  myMessages = [
    {
      id: 2,
      message: 'hello',
      changedText: false
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      message: 'world',
      changedText: false
    }
  ]

enableButton(itemId){
    this.myMessages.map( y => {if (y.id === itemId) {
      y.changedText = true;
    }});
  }

getMessageDetails(itemId){
    let myMessage = this.myMessages.find(y => y.id === itemId);
    return myMessage;
  }

saveMessageChanges(itemId, message){
    this.myMessages.map( y => {if (y.id === itemId) {
      y.message = message;
      y.changedText = false;
    }});
  }
discardChanges(itemId){
    let tempMessage = Object.assign({},(this.myMessages.find(y => y.id === itemId)));

    let myMessage = this.myMessages.find(y => y.id === itemId);

    myMessage.changedText = false;
    myMessage.message =  tempMessage.message; // <- no object change detected
    //myMessage.message = " " + tempMessage.message; // <- this works
    return myMessage;
  }
```

Whenever I add a whitespace to the message, it will work.

I created a stackblitz here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5dbj4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change detected because actually there is no change in the list `myMessages`. If you add the `{{myMessages | json }}` to your HTML and insert text into the text area you see that the content of the list does not change. In `discardChanges` you simply assign again "hello" to the variable which already holds the string "hello". So there is no change. 
If you add whitespace to the message in `discardChanges` (as you described) you actually change the value from "hello" to "hello " -> value changed.

However, you can overcome this problem by holding a "previous" list to keep track of the original entries of your list and the usage of ngModel.

Change the text area to

```
<textarea #message (keydown)="enableButton(itemId)" rows="5" cols="50" [(ngModel)]="getMessageDetails(itemId).message"></textarea>
```

And your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
  itemIds = [2,4];
  myMessages = [
    {
      id: 2,
      message: 'hello',
      changedText: false
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      message: 'world',
      changedText: false
    }
  ]

  previous = []

  ngOnInit() {
    this.previous = this.getDeepCopy(this.myMessages);
  }

  saveMessageChanges(itemId, message){
    this.myMessages.map( y => {if (y.id === itemId) {
      y.message = message;
      y.changedText = false;
    }});

    this.previous = this.getDeepCopy(this.myMessages);
  }

  discardChanges(itemId){
    this.myMessages = this.getDeepCopy(this.previous);
    let myMessage = this.myMessages.find(y => y.id === itemId);

    return myMessage;

  }

  getDeepCopy( list ) {
    return list.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
  }
}
```

I avoided some methods in the component because they are not relevant for this example. Just assign a deep copy to the variable `previous` at `ngOnInit` and also do this if you press save. If you want to discard changes, you reassign a deep copy of the list `previous` again to `myMessages`.

With this, your view updates because now there is a change of the variable value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I was thinking about copying as well, but I thought, maybe there is a way around it, which I did not think about.